# Trying to figure out the best way to send data to a server via android

Tags: android, sql-server, database, queue

I'm trying to figure out what the best method to send two strings and an integer to a server. Should I use a database? I want to achieve a queue effect and not really store the data online for too long. I just want to grab the information in the queue with a different program. The android would just need to send the data to the web server, but I'm not sure what kind of data structures I should be researching.

So I'm really looking for ideas of some kind of scripts I can be running on a web-server and how to implement sending to them via android. I don't need specific code, but an idea I could research would work too. I really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, Encode what you need to send in JSON and send it. I'll quote an example below, I have a server running Django and have set up an API to save the data into the database when I hit the url with a post request. I send the Location (latitude and longitude) along with the current datetime. On my server a view runs and parses the json and then saves it to DB.

In your case however you can just manipulate the data the way you want and not save it.

```
    try 
    {
            double la = 30.1955600 ;
            double lo = 71.4752800;
            Time t = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
            t.setToNow();
            String date = t.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");


            JSONObject o1 = null;                                                               
            o1 = new JSONObject();
            o1.put("latitude", loc.latitude);
            o1.put("longitude", loc.longitude);
            o1.put("date_added", date);




            // http call//
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost request = new HttpPost("the url you want to hit");

            StringEntity _params =new StringEntity(o1.toString());

            request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");

            request.setEntity(_params);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);    
    //check to see if we got a response

            if (response.getEntity() != null)
                HomeScreen.location_sent = true;
            else
                HomeScreen.location_sent = false;

    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.getMessage();
    }
```